# create application pages that look like OOB pages

Tags: application-pages

I want to create pages in SharePoint that look exactly like SharePoint pages. To have the same layout as the New Site Collection page, or new web application pages, I saw many solutions made this way, I am wondering how to do the same.

Comment: What you mean by look exactly like SharePoint pages? If you use the same masterpage, it should be the same.. Can you show us the screenshot of the differences you are observing?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the **Getting started with your site** look, then you can't unless you're building a new site collection.

[image]

But all of the features (and many, many more) are still available if you hit the gear Icon in the upper right corner and select **Site Settings**.